# How to get YouTube video Views from YouTube Data API?

Tags: rest, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

I am trying to get list of videos with title, upload, date, views, likes, dislikes, comments but I cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'viewCount') as runtime error.

```js
const YouTubeSearch = () => {
  const [keyword, setKeyword] = useState("");
  const [searchResults, setSearchResults] = useState([]);

  
  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search`,
        {
          params: {
            part: ["snippet","statistics"],
            q: keyword,
            type: "video",
            maxResults: 25,
            key: 'youtubeKey',
          },
        }
      );

      setSearchResults(response.data.items);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching data from YouTube API:", error);
    }
  };

  const renderSearchResults = () => {
    return (
      searchResults.map((item) => (
        <tr key={item.id}>
          <td>{item.snippet.title}</td>
          <td>{item.snippet.publishedAt}</td>
          <td>{item.statistics.viewCount}</td>
          <td>{item.statistics.likeCount}</td>
          <td>{item.statistics.dislikeCount}</td>
          <td>{item.statistics.commentCount}</td>
        </tr>
      ))
    );
  };
```

Runtime Error ->  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'viewCount')

How to solve this? How to get viewCount, likeCount, dislikeCount, commentCount?